# Json-server-auth, do I need to do something with access-token?

Tags: javascript, json

Json-server-auth, do I need to do something with access-token?
I'm doing authorization via json-server-auth, access token comes in the body of the response, do I need to do anything with it at all? Or is it automatically saved in localStorage? It seems to have done everything, everything works. But I didn't fully understand whether it was necessary to do something with him or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to store in localstorage. if you are going to logout user automatically after a certain time like 1 min or 1 hour or 1 daya etc, then it will we helpfull. Alos token can have other data like userId or non-sensitive data you want to use then it can be get from localstorage.

Comment: I was just sent a test task - to make a personal account with authorization, but I added more registration, just to understand, for myself. I have implemented registration, when registering a user is added to the database, everything works. In response I get access-token, but I do not use it in fact, just data that are returned set in the state (Redux in my case) is it necessary to save access-token in my case?

Comment: If you want to login the user when signup then you need to store the token, otherwise there is no need of token generation or store of the token. If you want to login the user directedly when user signup then you can store it.

Comment: Do you mean when I register after sending the data, I immediately get into a personal account, without confirming the mail? And if, say, I try to enter the account later, I make a login request, there comes a token and then it is constantly transmitted in requests?

Comment: Its depend on your requirements. If you want just signup then send an email to user with token, when he logged in then it will set to the local storage. Mainly this used while login the user.

Comment: I hope you will get my point

Comment: Well, I roughly understood, I just need to know how it works in practice, once you see and everything falls into place)